# OnTapGesture block breaks UserLocationButton in MapKit in SwiftUi

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit

```
struct AddRoomMap: View {
   @State private var position: MapCameraPosition = initialPosition
   @State private var selectedRoom: String?
   
   var body: some View {
       MapReader { reader in
           Map(initialPosition: initialPosition, selection: $selectedRoom){
               UserAnnotation()
           }
           .onTapGesture(perform: { screenCoord in
               let pinLocation = reader.convert(screenCoord, from: .local)
               print(pinLocation )
           })
           .mapControls({
               MapUserLocationButton()
               
           })
           .onAppear{
               CLLocationManager().requestAlwaysAuthorization()
           }
       }
   }
}
```

When i use mapReader and onTapGesture for getting location, it breaks UserLocationButton. if i press UserLocationButton, it gives me area location which is behind of button instead of going user's location.